# Как правильно? использование прилагательного или причастия

Tags: морфология

Как правильно сказать: оценивать актера по удачным ролям или по удавшимся ролям?

Comment: Обычно, говоря "удачные роли", имеют в виду "удавшиеся роли" и наоборот. Так что никакой разницы.

Comment: Очень интересное замечание о полном совпадении и о вкладываемом смысле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сугубое филологическое имхо:

удачная роль - та, с которой актёру повезло, она ему "по росту" и принесла успех;

удавшаяся - та, которую он любит, может, второго плана, может, кикимора какая, а лучше королевишны.

Иногда та и другая могут совпасть.

В "Москве слезам не верит" удачная роль у Алентовой, однако ж она локти кусала, что Муравьёва её переигрывает. А сама Муравьёва не любит роль Людмилы, кино не смотрит - такая, говорит, отпетая хамка получилась... Удавшаяся.

---

А актёра оценивать, вестимо, по ***удавшимся*** ролям.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина. Тонко подмечено и ясно истолковано. Теперь понятно.  Честно говоря, мне всегда казалось что во всех синонимичных и похожих словах или выражениях есть разница, присутствует пусть небольшое, но отличие. Ну вот вы дали еще одно подтверждение.    Вопрос, если можно: слово продавщица несет в себе негативную коннота́цию?

Comment: Не-а. Ну какой из Элизы Дулитл ***продавец*** цветов? Никакого негатива в продавщице. А где пятёрка за ответ, а?

Comment: Совершенно согласен (так же как и певица, кладовщица, мастерица). Просто у меня дискуссия была недавно.  "5" за ответ, так почту за честь, но как это сделать? Я тут человек новый. Когда нажимаю на "хороший ответ" - это учитывается но не публикуется. Вот такие дела. А друго пути не ведаю.

Comment: @Иваныч Сейчас Вы можете нажать стрелочку (треугольник) вверх, а также принять ответ галочкой.

Comment: Да, а ларчик то ...  :-)